# Question about a proposition on the exponentiation of sums of elements of a Ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, ring-theory

So my professor has the following theorem on his notes:

{ Let R be a ring, a, b ∈ R and n ∈ N. If ab = ba,
then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(a^k)b^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$$

But can´t i just say

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(a^k)b^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}(a^k)b^{n-k}=n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}(a^k)b^{n-k}=(a+b)^n$$?

which says that$(a+b)^n$ is always a multiple of n, which makes no sense.

I´m doing something very wrong here, but i can´t see it.

What is it?

Some help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is an integer?

Comment: Yep, that is the issue. Thank you very much!